# objectbox Pre-populate Database bulk insert

Tags: android, database, bulk, objectbox

I am Building an application in android using ObjectBox, but I have to store a huge json and processing it. In new devices this task take 2 minutes but in older devices it can take 5 - 7 minutes. I was thinking if there is an easy way to store the information in objectbox like a bulk action where the server send the information and the app just stored it.

PS: Each user need to store different information.

Comment: I don't know how many objects you are putting and how. ObjectBox typically can insert hundreds of thousands object per second.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you do not wrap your put operations in a transaction. For some background, please read https://docs.objectbox.io/transactions.

What you want to do is probably this:

```
boxStore.runInTx(() -> {
    // Your code here; e.g. box.put() in a processing loop for the JSON input
});
```